# Which is the plural of "forum": "fora" or "forums"?

Tags: plural-forms, word-form, latin

I'm active on many discussion **fora**, but I see that people more often use the form **forums**.

Are both forms correct and adequate?

If so, why are there two forms for the plural of such a short word?

Comment: This is a near-duplicate to an earlier question, "indexes" or "indices", because the answer is virtually the same: a link to a good general reference that will tell you.

Comment: I would add here more words (just for sake of searchability), `statuses`/`stati` and `bonuses`/`boni`.

Comment: Cacti, cactuses.....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although the proper Latin plural would be *fora*, *forum* has been adopted into the English language--and in most cases follows the rules of English pluralization. Similar changes can be seen with the adoption of other words like *octupus* (the proper plural would be more like [octopedes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural_form_of_words_ending_in_-us#Octopus), but in English we usually say either *octopi* or *octopuses*).

The current [entry](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/forum) from the Oxford Dictionary says:

> The plural of forum is usually spelled forums; the plural fora (as in the original Latin) is chiefly used when talking about a public square in an ancient Roman city.

Since you're talking about online discussion boards, I would use *forums* instead of *fora* when you are talking about more than one. An English speaker might understand *fora*, but it wouldn't come as naturally.

Answer (score 7):

There are two forms for the plural since *forum* came from the Latin (where its plural is *fora*) for *public place*.

From checking with Ngrams, around the 1930s, *forums* took over *fora*.

[image]